# NVIDIA settings do not persist

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, xorg

I have just moved to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 and am having problems with my NVIDIA settings. They do not persist if I restart the desktop or reboot the pc.

I've tried

sudo nvidia-xconfig

Which runs without error

And running nvidia-settings as root.

It's a new install so I'm pretty sure my nvidia-340 drivers are up to date.

It's a small inconvenience to run nvidia settings on reboot but it would be nice to fix it.

Below are the messages when I run nvidia settings as root. It looks like there are multiple problems that I have no idea how to fix.

And also the results from nvidia-xconfig

========================================================
sudo nvidia-settings

(nvidia-settings:4273): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:08:36.885: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
       have been installed along with this driver at either
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-340.108-key-documentation
       or /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

** (nvidia-settings:4273): WARNING **: 09:08:37.189: PRIME: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/prime-supported” (No such file or directory)
** Message: 09:08:37.190: PRIME: is it supported? no
Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-server.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-server' found
Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing`xorg-server.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

## No package 'xorg-server' found

sudo nvidia-xconfig

Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'

## New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'